# Why does springboot report errors when integrating mybatis and Druid?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, mybatis, druid

Error log:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
> bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource
> [com/ban/demo/conf/MybatisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via
> factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory
> method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping
> resource: 'URL
> [jar:file:/F:/repository4/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.39/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/org/apache/catalina/mapper/mbeans-descriptors.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error
> creating document instance.  Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> http://commons.apache.org/dtds/mbeans-descriptors.dtd

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan("com.ban.demo.**.dao")
public class MybatisConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setTypeAliasesPackage("com.ban.demo.**.model");    // 扫描Model
    
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(resolver.getResources("classpath*:**/mapper/*.xml"));    // 扫描映射文件

        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ban</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mysql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- druid -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- 打包时拷贝MyBatis的映射文件 -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/mapper/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
# Tomcat
server:
  tomcat:
    uri-encoding: UTF-8
#    max-threads: 1000
#    min-spare-threads: 30
  port: 8080
  #context-path: /springboot

# DataSource

    spring:
      datasource:
        name: druidDataSource
        type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
        druid:
          driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
          url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useUnicode=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
          username: root
          password: 123456
          filters: stat,wall,log4j,config
          max-active: 100
          initial-size: 1
          max-wait: 60000
          min-idle: 1
          time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 60000
          min-evictable-idle-time-millis: 300000
          validation-query: select 'x'
          test-while-idle: true
          test-on-borrow: false
          test-on-return: false
          pool-prepared-statements: true
          max-open-prepared-statements: 50
          max-pool-prepared-statement-per-connection-size: 20
```

Comment: MyBatis is trying to parse `org/apache/catalina/mapper/mbeans-descriptors.xml` because it matches the expression you specified i.e. `classpath*:**/mapper/*.xml`. Using narrower expression should fix the problem.